# Why crystal capacitors have to be close to each other?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, crystal

Atmel's [AVR186](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8128.pdf) document shows in page 2 a layout of two capacitors very close to each other and pointing in the same direction, also in page 3 they say: "The load capacitors should be placed close to each other." (despite "Reduce the parasitic capacitance between Xtalin and Xtalout pins by routing them as far
apart as possible." which sounds contradictory).

I wanted to know why to place them like this, so close to each other. My guess is since there is apparently an inversor amplifier inside the MCU, the current in them is always in opposite direction so the induced magnetic fields will cancel with each other and it's inductance will better. But I am not sure this is the reason and if the current is circulating in them in the same direction, this can be twice as worse since the fields will couple adding each other.

Comment: *inversor amplifier*? Inverting amplifier? Didn't edit because I wasn't sure what you meant, sorry.

Comment: In the diagram there is a "triangle with a circle in the point" which usually is something that inverts the input and since its driving a load and its a big triangle I believe it's an amplifier as well, the correct name in English I am not sure (I am not American) so be free to edit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a strong RF current flowing through the capacitors of a crystal oscillator. In order to keep this current from coupling to/from free space (EMI considerations), it is necessary to keep the loop area of this circuit as small as possible.

In this case, the "loop" is the complete path through the crystal and the two capacitors. If you don't keep these components as close together as possible, the loop area will be larger than it needs to be.

Comment: So they can't be opposed to each other (like a cross and not ending together like in the datasheet)  because the return current to the ground pin will make a big turn for one of them right?